# Motorcycle won't start or show signs of life

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, yamaha

So a few months ago my Motorcycle (Yamaha XJ550 Maxim 1982) Decided just to lay down and die, I tried starting it over a billion times and it made a few buzzing noises and then stopped, lights won't shine, horn won't even make a sing noise, I've bought a new battery and charged it for hours and it still has not made any noise to signal any life, Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the fuses?

Comment: Yes, I have and the fuse box has some of the clips broken so unfortunately, I can't replace it due to parts being either pricey or hard to find.

Comment: Pretty much everything but the starting circuit goes through those fuses, so probing the clips either side of the fuses with a multimeter or light-up voltage probe is the next step.

Comment: "I'm just bad at everything electrical" Don't worry, in my experience most hobby mechanics are ;). Fortunately, electrical problems on a 1982 bike may be easier to diagnose than a newer one.

Comment: Are you talking about the metal *clips* which hold the fuses in place?

Comment: @Sam - Yes, that's what Phil is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As *Phil G* states, first you need to make sure all the fuses are working.**

If part of the fuse box is broken, you do not need to replace the entire box. Below is a picture of a fuse box similar to the one in your bike. You can see that the second fuse and wiring is missing. What the owner did was replace the second fuse in the box with an **inline fuse holder**. It is the white plastic tube to the left of the fuse box.

[image: OEM fuse box and aftermarket inline fuse]

The tube-type of inline fuse holder is very common. It holds a traditional glass-tube fuse. I prefer the newer **inline blade fuse holder**, shown below. They are smaller, and provide better protection from the elements. Both types typically cost less than $5, and can be purchased at any auto parts store.

[image: inline blade fuse holder]

[This site](https://www.retrobikegear.com/blog/how-to-install-an-inline-fuse-holder-on-a-vintage-motorcycle/) has a good guide on how to replace an old motorcycle fuse box with newer inline fuses. **You only need to replace the fuses which have broken clips.**

Comment: You can get complete 4 or 6 gang replacement fuseboxes for a few bucks from the online stores, that take the newer blade fuses too. Just crimp on 1/4" terminals to the existing wiring and plug in. https://www.ebay.com/itm/Black-Fuse-Holder-Box-4-Way-Car-Vehicle-Circuit-Automotive-Blade-Fuse-Box/184044730633

Comment: I'm a little late but thank you guys so much, this will help a lot I will inform you of my results :)